# AJAX inside IFRAME not working against same server

Tags: ajax, iframe

I'm using a website, `abc.com`, that is hosting an `iframe` of a page on `123.com`.
The page inside the `iframe` is doing an AJAX request to another page on `123.com`, but we're seeing that the request is getting cancelled.

Unless I'm wrong — *and I haven't found any official information on the internet about this* — the call should work fine as it is not a cross-domain request.

Would the fact that the parent frame is on a different domain really hinder the `iframe` from doing AJAX requests to its own server?

Comment: Can we see it in action? Are there any options in the iframe? Is this happening with a specific browser?

Comment: Can you at least copy paste the full error message (from FireBug or the dev console) to provide more information?

Comment: May be something to do with SSL. I did a quick search and found this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756526/jquery-ajax-call-fails-and-returns-error-on-facebook-iframes

Answer (score 3):

The IFRAME should be able to make an ajax request to its own originating site (same source URL). However, make sure the REQUEST event is FIRED from the IFRAME, not the parent.

My first guess would be you are loading the IFRAME and then addressing it (firing an event) via the parent (JS) to get it to do/get/set something which triggers an ajax call. In short, this is the mostly likely reason the IFRAME domain to same domain request is getting cancelled as it is still recognized by the browser as originating from outside the target domain code.

The REQUEST event needs to be ***organically*** generated from the **user** clicking on something in the IFRAME or **from code in the IFRAME itself** firing the event.

**In other words:** just because the IFRAME may have some ability to fire events/ajax in its JS/code to/from itself, it would normally still *not be allowed* to have the parent reference that ajax/JS directly via JS/code. The IFRAME has to already be coded to do it based on its load parameters (URL values, perhaps) or the user has to physically click/take action on something to create a user generated event on that domain.

Of course, this is going to vary a bit by browser and version on what you might be able coax in terms interactivity between the parent and iframe. But a strict, up-to-date browser will try to keep you from faking insecure interaction on the iFrame via js.

To get a better answer, you would need to provide more detail on exactly what you are doing/getting.